# Set string variable in C from argv[1]

Tags: c, variables

I am trying to learn C, and I wonder why this doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char testvar[] = argv[0];
    //do something with testvar

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
char *testvar = argv[0];
```

Or maybe:

```
char *testvar = strdup(argv[0]);
/* Remember to free later. */
```

*As [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) notes, `strdup` isn't standard. Implementing it using malloc + memcpy is a nice exercise.*

Or even:

```
char testvar[LENGTH];
if (strlen(argv[0]) >= LENGTH)
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is too long!\n");
else
    strcpy(testvar, argv[0]);
```

But then again you might be looking for:

```
char testvar[] = "testvar";
```

Answer (score 4):

That syntax is valid only to initialize a `char` array from a literal, i.e. when you explicitly write in the source code what characters must be put in the array.

If you just want a pointer to it (i.e. "another name" to refer to it) you can do:

```
char * testvar = argv[0];
```

if instead you want a *copy* of it you have to do:

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[0]);
char * testvar = malloc(len+1);
if(testvar==NULL)
{
    /* allocation failed */
}
strcpy(testvar, argv[0]);
/* ... */
free(testvar);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a constant to initialize an object. `argv[0]` is not a constant.
`"foobar"` below is a constant

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc char **argv) {
    char array[] = "foobar"; /* array has 7 elements */
    char *testvar;

    testvar = malloc(strlen(argv[0]) + 1); /* remember space for the NUL terminator */
    if (testvar != NULL) {
        strcpy(testvar, argv[0]);
        /* do something with testvar */
        free(testvar);
    } else {
        /* report allocation error */
    }
    return 0;
}
```